# Compact set $K_\epsilon\subset B$ such that $\ell^*(B\setminus K_\epsilon) \leq \epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

This is from Bartle's book:

> If B is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb R$, if $\epsilon >0$ and $B\subset I_n=(n,n+1] $, then there exists a compact set $K_\epsilon\subset B$ such that $\ell^*(K_\epsilon)\leq \ell^*(B) \leq \ell^*(K_\epsilon)+\epsilon.$

Here $\ell^*$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on the line and $F^*$ the family of lebesgue measurable sets. I tried the following proof:

We note that $\bar I_n = [n,n+1] \in F^*$. Hence, $\bar I_n\setminus B \in F^*$ and given $\epsilon >0$, I know from a previous exercise that exists $G_\epsilon$ open such that $\bar I_n\setminus B \subset G_\epsilon$ and $\ell^*(\bar I_n\setminus B) \leq \ell^*(G_\epsilon) \leq \ell^*(\bar I_n \setminus B) + \epsilon$. Since $\bar I_n \setminus B \subset G_{\epsilon}$ we guarantee that $I_n\setminus G_\epsilon \subset B$. Define $K = \bar I_n\setminus G_\epsilon$ which is compact, since its closed and bounded. Hence:

$$\ell^*(\bar I_n\setminus B) \leq \ell^*(G_\epsilon) \leq (\bar I_n\setminus B) \implies \ell^*(I_n) \leq \ell^*(G_{\epsilon}) + \ell^*(B) \leq \ell^*(\bar I_n) \implies $$

$$\ell^*(\bar I_n) - \ell^*(G_\epsilon) \leq \ell^*(B) \leq \ell^*(\bar I_n) - \ell^*(G_\epsilon)$$

**but** I can't ensure that $\ell^*(\bar I_n) - \ell^*(G_\epsilon) = \ell^*(\bar I_n\setminus G_\epsilon) = \ell^*(K),$ since we don't know wheter $G_\epsilon \subset \bar I_n$ or not.

Any help on how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: generally the notation $\ell ^*$ is reserved for the outer Lebesgue measure, and $\ell $ for the Lebesgue measure (instead of $\ell $ the letters $m$ and $\lambda $ are also commonly used to represent the Lebesgue measure). This is as you will see in almost any textbook of measure theory, not only related to the Lebesgue measure. By example is generally written $\mu^*$ for the outer measure and $\mu$ for the measure, for any chosen measure

Comment: Bartle's book states at page 104 that $\ell^*$ denotes the Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 0):

$I_n\setminus B\subset(n,n+1]$ and there is a covering (because of the definition of the Lebesgue measure) such that $I_n\setminus B\subset\cup_i(a_i,b_i]$ and: $$l^*(I_n\setminus B)\leq \sum_il^*(a_i,b_i]<l^*(I_n\setminus B)+\frac{\epsilon}{4}$$

By taking $J_{-1}=(n+1-\frac{\epsilon}{8},n+1+\frac{\epsilon}{8})$, $J_0=(n-\frac{\epsilon}{8},n+\frac{\epsilon}{8})$ and also $J_i=(a_i,b_i+\epsilon/(4\cdot2^{i}))\cap (n,n+1)$, these still cover $I_n\setminus B$ and also:

$$l^*(I_n\setminus B)\leq l^*(\cup_i J_i)\leq \sum_i l^*(J_i)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\sum_{i\geq 1}(b_i-a_i)+\frac{\epsilon}{4}\leq l^*(I_n\setminus B)+\epsilon $$

By adding $l^*(B)$ to both sides of this inequality, we have:

$$ l^*(I_n)\leq l^*(\cup_i J_i)+l^*(B)\leq l^*(I_n)+\epsilon$$

By looking at the righthandside of this inequality and noticing $\cup_i J_i$ has finite measure and $(\cup_i J_i) \cap I_n\subset \cup_i J_i $ yields:

$$l^*(B)\leq l^*(I_n)-l^*(\cup_i J_i)+\epsilon\leq l^*(I_n\cap (\cup_iJ_i)^C)+\epsilon$$

Finaly we take $K_\epsilon=(\cup J_i)^C\cap[n,n+1]$ which is clearly compact.

Also, $K_\epsilon=\cap J_i^C\cap(n,n+1]$ because $n\not\in J_o^C$ but this implies:

$$I_n\setminus B\subset (\cup J_i)\Rightarrow (\cup J_i)^C\subset I_n^C\cup B\Rightarrow K_\epsilon \subset B$$

We still need to prove the inequality in your problem but this follows from the fact that $K_\epsilon\subset B$ and from the inequality we have already established:

$$l^*(K_\epsilon)\leq l^*(B)\leq l^*(I_n\cap(\cup_i J_i)^C)+\epsilon=l^*(K_\epsilon)+\epsilon$$